# Type check parameter is a (sub)class and also implements an interface

Tags: java

This answer no doubt exists on SO, but I haven't found the right combination of search terms to come up with it.

I have a method that I want to take a parameter that is of class A, but also implements interface B. How do I do it?

e.g.

```
public class MySubclassWithInterface extends MyClass implements MyInterface { }

public class MySubclass extends MyClass { }

public class MyInterfaceClass implements MyInterface { }

public class MyOtherSubclassWithInterface extends MyClass implements MyInterface { }
```

Out of the three classes above, I only want my method to accept an object that is `MyClass` and implements `MyInterface`, in other words, either `MySubclassWithInterface` or `MyOthersubclassWithInterface` but not `MySubclass` or `MyIntefaceClass`

I very sheepishly tried the following which obviously failed:

```
public void myMethod( (MyClass MyInterface) parameterName) {
...
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can express this with a generic type as in the following signature:

```
<T extends MyClass & MyInterface> void m(T p)
```

The rule is that the first type must be a class or an interface and any following parameter must be an interface type.